# How to hide asp.net querystring displayed in address bar as default.aspx?id=2&name=sanjay

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a querystring from url in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957457/removing-a-querystring-from-url-in-asp-net)

How to hide asp.net querystring displayed in address bar as default.aspx?id=2&name=sanjay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide the data passed in parameters in the query string.

1. Use a form and POST the information. This might require additional code in source pages, but should not require logic changes in the target pages (merely change Request.QueryString to Request.Form). While POST is not impossible to muck with, it's certainly less appealing than playing with QueryString parameters.
2. Use session variables to carry information from page to page. This is likely a more substantial effort compared to (1), because you will need to take session variable checking into account (e.g. the user might now have a difficult time navigating around using their Back and Forward buttons, if you are constantly checking state). You will also need to deal with the case where session cookies are not enabled (this solution will not work for these people).
3. Use "encoded" or non-sensical information in the QueryString in place of the real data. This will require the effort of creating an encoding and decoding scheme on either end of all page submissions. Sure, users can still experiment and reverse engineer your scheme, however they will be less likely to quickly come up with meaningful changes to the existing QueryString.
4. Use framesets. I really don't recommend this approach, though it is quite common. If you're trying to hide the information as opposed to making it more difficult to modify, users can still right-click the individual frames and click properties, in order to retrieve all of the information passed via QueryString.
5. Use Server.Transfer to move control to a second page, which will still have access to the QueryString parameters passed to the first page (the URL of which was visible only briefly)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to POST the data -- directly to default.aspx, if possible.  If the caller is a different page, this gets a little wonky with web forms, especially if you're relying on sitemap functionality.  In any case, you could post the data using "cross page posting" or you could use "server.transfer".  Using session state with a redirect is somewhat inefficient (an extra round trip for the client), but often expedient.  So for example, the calling page may look like:

**Web Form (caller):**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Click Me!</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Code-behind (caller):**

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["id"] = 2;  // pull the data from the control or use OnCommand?
    Session["name"] = "Sanjay";
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

And the receiving page, default.aspx would look like:

**Web Form:**

```
Name: <%=_name %>
<br />
Id: <%= _id %>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected int? _id
{
    get { return Session["id"] as int?; }
    set { Session["id"] = value; }
}
protected string _name
{
    get { return Session["name"] as string; }
    set { Session["name"] = value; }
}
```

Good luck!