# How hide a download url from our web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, hide

I have the following code in my page:

```
if (Request.QueryString("link_id") == "12345" )
{
    Responce.Redirect("http://www.downloadsite.com/blablabla.png");
}
```

Now I want to hide that URL when somebody adds this link to his internet download manager :

```
http://www.mysite.com?link_id=12345
```

as you see the goal domain in different, I just want prevent my users to share my links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use tinyurl  http://tinyurl.com/#hide

Comment: refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957457/removing-a-querystring-from-url-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do...are you saying that you want it to appear as if they're downloading from `http://www.mysite.com?link_id=12345` instead of `http://www.downloadsite.com/blablabla.png`?

Comment: Yes Tim S. That is exactly what i want...

Comment: tinyurl is not a good idea, because at last my users can find main link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you're trying to let the user download a file from `http://www.downloadsite.com/blablabla.png` that appears to the user, in every sense, to be coming from `http://www.mysite.com?link_id=12345`. This is what I'd try:

```
if (Request.Params["link_id"] == "12345")
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.downloadsite.com/blablabla.png");
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    using (var download = wc.OpenRead(uri))
    using (var respStream = Response.OutputStream)
        download.CopyTo(respStream);
}
```

Comment: really thanks for the answer / but that download pop-up does not come up...what is wrong?

Comment: i am so sorry for my dely, would you please consider to my prev comment!

Comment: You might be looking to set the `content-disposition` to `attachment`, to tell the browser it should download the content, instead of trying to display it inline. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header You might also want to make sure the MIME type (Content-Type) and any other metadata is set correctly. To see metadata from the original URL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome or search for "see http headers".

Comment: i have many .mkv (movies) next blablabla.png / did your solution work for thsoe files?

Comment: Yep, it should work for any file type; the only thing that'll be different is the source URL and, if you specify it, the Content-Type.

Comment: would you please complete your answer for a mkv file, i do n't want that file to be downloaded on my server...